# TCR hash functions from MD5

Tags: hash, md5, collision-resistance

I'm reading [Collision-Resistant Hashing: Towards Making UOWHFs Practical](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.77.2291&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pag. 10 and 11) and here say

> The most direct way to construct a TCR hash function is to key a function like MD5 or SHA-1.
>   ...
>
> A safer approach might be to incorporate key bits throughout the
>   message being hashed. For example, with $|K| = 128$ one might
>   intertwine $128$ bits of key and the next 384 bits of message into
>   every 512-bit block. (For example, every fourth byte might consist of
>   key.) Now the cryptanalyst's job amounts to finding a collision
>   $M,M'$ in MD5 where we have pre-specified a large number of (random)
>   values to be sprinkled in particular places throughout $M$ and $M'$ .
>   This would seem to be very hard.

... But if I add keys bits throughout the message being hashed; for me, nothing prevents fall in the MD5 again (MD5 is broken), then my question is Why that approach is safer?

Comment: MD5 being broken only means that an attacker can find collisions when its used without a key.